# Use ajax result to appendTo with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following Situation

```
success: function(data){
    $(data).appendTo($("#content-recent")).slideDown("slow");
}
```

but that doesn't work. I've tried to make the data (what basically is just plain html/text) to a jQuery object to be able to use appendTo but no trys work.

Someone an idea how it can be done?

Regards

Comment: What exactly does not work? Can you log the emerging object? Is the `success` callback executed at all, log the exact value of `data`?

Comment: any errors in the log?

Comment: no erros. console.out is correct and no other erros

Answer (score 0):

remove the $() from the brackets

```
$(data).appendTo("#content-recent")
```

but reading the documentation something else is at hand.

see http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ULwjR/ for either

Comment: If I don't use the $("#content-recent") it does not append

Comment: The output is correct: success: function(data){
                $(data).appendTo($("#content-recent"));
                console.log(data);
            }
it just doesn't append

Comment: $("#content-recent").append(data);
works by the way. Just the other way around not

Comment: what exactly is in data?

Comment: data is just something like "image added, status updated, article posted .." just plain text

Comment: Please look in the network tab to see if the data arrives and alert it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second `$`: your code should be

```
success: function(data){
    $(data).appendTo("#content-recent").slideDown("slow");
}
```

Comment: and also the same as my comment and answer